# How do I get Visual Studio Intellisense tooltips to show descriptions for .NET Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I need to use .NET framework 3.5 for my project because it uses some older functionality.

The tooltips in Visual Studio aren't showing descriptions like they do when targeting a later framework. I just see basic information like method signatures and data types. Is there a way to fix this?

I looked for the xml files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5` and it looks like it just has the files for the 3.5 Client Profile.

I tried reinstalling the 3.5 framework from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21

I have no idea if it's working or not. When I run the executable nothing happens. I tried running as administrator. When I run it from command prompt there is no output.

I noticed the file is a hundred times smaller that the download for the latest .NET framework. Does that mean it doesn't include the files it's supposed to?

I'm guessing if there's a fix, it's either getting the correct xml files for .NET 3.5 or getting Visual Studio to use the xml files for .NET 4.6 even though my project is targeting 3.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. (VS2015 on windows 10) It looks as if only 3.5 Client Profile is installed, but downloading and running the installer for 3.5 does nothing. It just exits instantly without any error. I don't want to switch to another framework version just to see intellisense descriptions!

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/37500027/533837](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37500027/533837)

Comment: I think you need to download and install the .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637 Note: .Net Frameworks are backward compatible.

Answer (score 5):

You could try downloading the whole installer not just the bootloader installer.

> **.net 3.5 sp1**
>
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

or if you dont want sp1

> **.net 3.5**
>
> http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe

**Edit**
If you are unable to run the installer at all it sounds to me like it is already installed. You could try to verify the installation using this [tool](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/05/netfx_setupverifier_new.zip). This [page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/) also explains how to find the setup logs. It should shed some light on what is happening.

Comment: Don't know about OP, but I already tried that (the .net 3.5 sp1 link you posted) - same result: the executable instantly quits with no error. Doesn't matter if I'm running it as admin either. It quits so fast I can't even see it pop up in the taskmanager. Tried running it from powershell too - as soon as I press enter it's instantly quits - nothing happens.

Comment: Tried it with the non-sp1 file. Tried running as administrator. Tried it in an elevated command prompt. Still does nothing. Exits with no error code. Nothing.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the earlier versions of .net provide the level of tooltips that your after unfortunately. One last thing you could try is to ensure you have all of the elements in the "Add windows programs and features" enabled. Not sure what version of windows your running on but this should explain what I mean:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10

> You can enable the .NET Framework 3.5 through the Windows Control Panel. This option requires an Internet connection.
>
> 1. Press the Windows key Windows Windows logo on your keyboard, type "Windows Features", and press Enter. The Turn Windows features on or off dialog box appears.
> 2. Select the .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)
>      check box, select OK, and reboot your computer if prompted.
>
> [image: Windows Features]

Comment: Please include relevant quotes from your links so that your answer is still useful if the link breaks.  [answer]

Comment: Already did that, and I am running win10. As for that intellisense information not being there before.... now I can't actually remember anymore. Surely it was there - is what I'd like to say, but now I'm starting to doubt my own memory. Seems a bit odd to me though that it *is* there if you run 3.5 ClientProfile, but not when you run 3.5 FullProfile. :/