# Visual Studio 2017 - Intellisense doesn't display documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, intellisense

I'm having an issue with the intellisense in VS2017. It shows me autocompletion and I can access to < summary> < /summary> of my **own** methods, however when I hover on anything else, I only get this:

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td0Uu.png)

I would like to get the full documentation, like on this subject:

[Visual Studio not showing IntelliSense descriptions anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500027/visual-studio-not-showing-intellisense-descriptions-anymore/37586115)

I'm actually having the exact same problem, and I tried many solutions, but nothing works for my case - or I didn't get it since sometimes it's very unclear.
I'm still a beginner with VS which I'm using with Unity (I started few days ago).

Comment: @JosephCho this has nothing to do with code written by Riyujin. What should he post? What example? This is a config problem in VS.

Comment: You are right @nilSK. My mistake.

Comment: Do you have the correct Visual Studio extensions installed? Have you installed the C# and Unity package?

Comment: Yes I have "Unity 2018.3 64-bit Editor" and "Visual Studio Tools pour Unity" installed as well as "C# and visual basics"

Comment: @Riyujin, could you please share the detail information about the <Summary></Summary>? Please have a look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#walkthrough

Comment: Well I just meant to say, if I do my own < summary> documentation on my methods and then I hover over them, it works. However I do not have the documentation of the built-in methods like for exemple "Input.getAxis()". I only have what's on the screenshot.